# Transforming a matrix to a binary matrix with 1 at minimum of row

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

I have a question with a part of an assignment. We need to program everything as linear equations (no max or min functions allowed).

Say for example that I have a matrix D with the distances:

```
5   8 12
13 20  5
40 15  5
```

How would I convert this into a binary matrix through linear programming that gives the value 1 at the minimum of each row and 0 otherwise?

Thus

```
1 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 1
```

Comment: Are these two matrices supposed to be variables or parameters?

Comment: (also, is the brief "no max or min functions anywhere in the code" or "the optimisation problem must be a linear problem"? The difference might be important here.)

Comment: Both matrices are variables: since they depend on a max distance U
(1 if smaller than U, 0 otherwise)
It must be a linear optimisation problem, which does not allow max/min functions in any of the constraints, right?

Comment: It'd be fine to have max/min functions that are defined solely on the parameters (since those can be evaluated before optimising) which is why I wanted to clarify, but it sounds as if that's not what you're asking for. Are you able to give a bit more information about how these matrices are used in the problem? (Also, is the first matrix guaranteed to be integer?)